# visual studio windows phone 7 installation error

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-7

I try to install latest Visual Studio Windows Phone Beta Tools and I get following error:

"Setup could not install the following component:
Microsoft .NET Framework 4"

Here is the error log: http://pastebin.com/CRumcpsN . I'm running under Windows 7 32bit.

What I have to do to install Visual Studio Windows Phone Beta Tools?

Comment: I believe this is the wrong place for this post. You should either post this in the Windows Phone 7 forums (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/category/windowsphone) or possibly the Super User stack exchange site.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the .NET 4 framework first http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9cfb2d51-5ff4-4491-b0e5-b386f32c0992&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you downloaded the correct WP7DT version? I noticed this in your dump.

```
dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe; error = 0x80091007
```